# Persistent DynamoDB Connection in Node.j app

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

Inside the app, I make lots of use of the Dynamodb(gets, pushes, scans, etc.)
Should I create a new connection to the Dynamodb every time i need to interact with the DB(on multiple modules), or should I just have one open connection for the entire app. 
Ive found some very vague information regarding this. 
If i am to make just a single connection, can you point me in the right direction on doing this (dynamodb-connect?)

Answer (score 1):

The DynamoDB client object in node.js is thread safe so creating a single instance and using that for all of your interactions is fine.

DynamoDB is interacted with using HTTP REST and not with a persistent TCP connection the way SQL databases like MySQL are.  This means the benefit would be reusing the HTTP connecting using a keep alive.